# Running count of distinct values in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have data stored as below in an MS Access database:

```
Date         User
20090101     1001
20090101     1002
20090102     1001
20090103     1001
20090103     1003
```

I'm attempting to create a query which shows the daily running count of unique users.  For example:

```
Date        Daily Count   Unique User Running Count
20090101    2             2
20090102    1             2
20090103    2             3
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most SQL implementations you could select using the aggregate function count(distinct user).  But Access doesn't support that construct.  I think the best you could do is to select the distinct values in a subquery and count them.

I was going to write a query but this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx) seems to do a good job.

HTH
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Your query will look something like this...can't test it without the data though:

```
SELECT Date, Count(Date) As [Daily Count], Count(User) As [Unique User Running Count]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Access Count() counts all values, not just distinct.

Comment: When there is a GROUP BY clause, the Count() should only count the elements in the group...in this case, it would be how many for each distinct Date.

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately, that doesn't give the OPs desired result for the running count field.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!  A simple solution is the best: no SQL coding needed.

[image]

In Access, Query Design,

```
Column 1 = 
Field=Date
tablename=yourname
Total=Groupby
Column2 =
Field=Date
Table=yourname
Total=Count
```