# Access - Get distinct count of rows based on different column values

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database with the following format:

```
ID  | Period  | Data
---------------------
13  | 1       | xxxxx
13  | 2       | xxxxx
25  | 1       | xxxxx
25  | 2       | xxxxx
25  | 3       | xxxxx
52  | 1       | xxxxx
52  | 3       | xxxxx
94  | 1       | xxxxx
94  | 2       | xxxxx
94  | 3       | xxxxx
```

The Period can be 1, 2, or 3.  I need to get a count of the IDs that have a period of 1, 2, and 3, or periods 1 and 2, or 1 and 3 (they always have period 1).  How can I run such a query - it can be 3 different queries to hit the different permutations.  The results would be like the following:

***Periods 1, 2, and 3:***
***Count: 2*** (for IDs 25 and 94, although I don't necessarily need the IDs returned, just the count)

***Periods 1 and 2:***
***Count: 1 (ID 13)***

***Periods 1 and 3:***
***Count: 1 (ID 52)***

Is this possible with Access?  It's not quite distinct values, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857872/running-count-of-distinct-values-in-access) and the [linked article](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx) don't seem to provide enough help.  I don't have the database yet which is why I can't test that query, but I want to know if it would be possible before creating the table or if I need to find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to create a transform query like this and save it

```
TRANSFORM Count(YourTable.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT YourTable.ID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourTable.ID
PIVOT YourTable.Period)
```

Which outputs

```
ID  1 2 3
--  - - -
13  1 1 
25  1 1 1
52  1   1
94  1 1 1
```

You can then use that create another query Lke this

```
SELECT t.Groups, Count(t.ID) AS CountOfID
FROM (SELECT ID, 
     SWITCH(
               [1] = 1 and [2] =1 and [3] = 1, 'Periods 1, 2, and 3',
               [1] = 1 and [2] =1 , 'Periods 1 and 2',
               [1] = 1 and [3] =1 , 'Periods 1 and 3'
               )  as Groups

FROM TheSavedTransformQuery)  AS t
GROUP BY t.Groups;
```

Which outputs this

```
Groups              CountOfID
------------------- ---------
Periods 1 and 2        1
Periods 1 and 3        1
Periods 1, 2, and 3    2
```

If you want to do it as single SQL statement this will work as well

```
SELECT 
    t.Groups, 
    Count(t.ID) AS CountOfID
FROM (

    SELECT 
        Switch(
            FirstPeriod.Period=1 And [SecondPeriod.Period ]=2 And [ThirdPeriod.Period]=3,'Periods 1, 2, and 3',
            FirstPeriod.Period=1 And [SecondPeriod.Period]=2,'Periods 1 and 2',
            FirstPeriod.Period=1 And [ThirdPeriod.Period]=3,'Periods 1 and 3') AS Groups, 
            DistinctID.ID
    FROM (((SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM 
        YourTable )  AS DistinctID 

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, PERIOD 
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE Period = 1)  AS FirstPeriod 

        ON DistinctID.ID = FirstPeriod.ID) 

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, PERIOD 
        FROM YourTable  WHERE Period = 2)  AS SecondPeriod 
        ON DistinctID.ID = SecondPeriod.ID) 

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, PERIOD 
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE Period = 3)  AS ThirdPeriod 
        ON DistinctID.ID = ThirdPeriod.ID

)AS t
GROUP BY 
    t.Groups
```