# access filter needed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Here is a sample data set

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id   nameid   name        score         diff          include     quantity     grade
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

7     0002     MO          10            0                0          25          3
8     0002     MO          18            0                1          25          3
9     0002     MO          20            0                0          25          3
10    0002     MO          14            0                0          17          6
11    0002     MO          100           0                0          17          6
11    0002     MO          100           0                0          17          6

12    0003     MA          10            0                0          12          3 
13    0003     MA          18            0                0          12          3
14    0003     MA          20            0                0          12          3
15    0003     MA          14            0                0          25          6
16    0003     MA          100           0                1          25          6
17    0003     MA          100           0                0          25          6

12    0004     MB          10            0                0          12          3
13    0004     MB          18            0                1          12          3
14    0004     MB          20            0                0          12          3 
15    0004     MB          14            0                0          07          6
16    0004     MB          100           0                1          07          6
17    0004     MB          100           0                0          07          6
```

I have a query that returns the above table. 
Note that in each group of six, there WILL be atleast one row that has value `1` in  `include` column.
Look at ref: [access query needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508970/access-query-needed)  but not needed.

Also for each group of six, there are three rows that has `grade = 3` and 3 rows that has `grade = 6`. 
And corresspondingly, the `grade 3` and `grade 6` have the same quantity in that group.

What I want to do is filter out all the rows that have less then 15 quantity. 
However, I still want to group them by 6.

I want to remove a "group" that has both `quantity < 15` for both grade 3 and 6. From the above data set
I wwant the following result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id   nameid   name        score         diff          include     quantity     grade
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

7     0002     MO          10            0                0          25          3
8     0002     MO          18            0                1          25          3
9     0002     MO          20            0                0          25          3
10    0002     MO          14            0                0          17          6
11    0002     MO          100           0                0          17          6
11    0002     MO          100           0                0          17          6

12    0003     MA          10            0                0          12          3 
13    0003     MA          18            0                0          12          3
14    0003     MA          20            0                0          12          3
15    0003     MA          14            0                0          25          6
16    0003     MA          100           0                1          25          6
17    0003     MA          100           0                0          25          6
```

So basically if a group of six has `include = 1` in any row, and either grade 3 or 6 `quantity > 15` then I want the entire group.

Comment: the column `nameid` can have upto 6 of the same names.

Comment: I have edited a few columns that I should've done before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*So basically if a group of six has include = 1 in any row, and either grade 3 or 6 quantity > 15 then I want the entire group.*"

My guess is this query will identify the candidate nameid groups:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nameid
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    include = 1
    AND quantity > 15
    AND (grade = 3 OR grade = 6);
```

If I guessed correctly, you can save it as a separate query, or use it as a subquery, and INNER JOIN it to YourTable to limit the rows returned to only those where nameid meets your criteria.  It might look close to this untested SELECT statement:

```
SELECT y.id, y.nameid, y.[name], y.score, y.diff, y.include, y.quantity, y.grade
FROM
    YourTable AS y
    INNER JOIN [
        SELECT DISTINCT nameid
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE
            include = 1
            AND quantity > 15
            AND (grade = 3 OR grade = 6)
        ]. AS q
        ON y.nameid = q.nameid
ORDER BY y.nameid;
```

**Edit**:  Add an index on nameid if you don't already have one.

Comment: right I think that works. just need to QA on that. However it is a bit on the slow side. I can't add an index on the table.. since the table itself is another query.

Comment: If there's no other practical solution, consider creating an auxiliary table to hold those DISTINCT nameid values.  You could convert that one query into an "append query" ... `INSERT INTO AuxTable (nameid) SELECT DISTINCT nameid FROM YourTable...`  Then INNER JOIN YourTable with AuxTable ON nameid.  That approach wouldn't be my first choice, but if it gives enough performance improvement, and you can't find a better way, .... try it.  :-)